# Error "control reaches end of non-void function"

Tags: c

I am getting error in these program which take array, its size, and and element to be search in that array.

An error is coming "control reaches end of non-void function" while i try to run it.

Also some compilers are not giving errors, they run this code properly.

So i want to know reason in behind this and how i can solve this error?

Also i tried to search this error on stackoverflow i find some questions but i dont get them. Please help me.

```
int search(unsigned long int a[], unsigned long int n, unsigned long int search)        
{
    unsigned long int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (a[i] == search)     
        {
            return 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (i == n)
    {
        return 0;
    }

}
```

Comment: Think what happens when `i != n` in the end. Though you now this should not be possible, the compiler cannot know. Since you already return from inside the for loop instead of break (which I assume is left there by accident), remove the `if` at the end.

Comment: This error is not a runtime one but a compile time. It is due to the fact that compilers are unable to see that the last condition never fails. Just add a "fake" `return` at the end of the function.

Comment: @IljaEverilä okk I got it, so I have to just write else{ return 1}. After that if.  Thank-you

Comment: @JayPatel Just have `return 0` after `for` loop